# Python - View an imported module's dotted import

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I want to get all the modules imported from an arbitrary module `m`.
When `m` imports a module in the following way:

```
from a.b import c
```

or:

```
import a.b.c as c
```

(where `a` and `b` are packages, and `c` is a module)

The result of `dir(m)` would contain `c` (among other things).

However, when I use:

```
import a.b.c
```

The result of `dir(m)` would contain `a`, and not `c`.

I also tried iterating over `sys._getframe(1).f_locals.items()` after importing `m`, but got the same result.
How can I, having the object of `m` that imports `c` that way, know that it actually imported `c`?

Comment: Not very clear that do you exactly want, if c is a module then c is the module itself, anyway depends of your project structure and the content of `__init__.py` of each package

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: I want to get all the imported modules from an arbitrary module `m`. Now if `m` imported `c` that way (`import a.b.c`), I won't get `c` by iterating over `dir(m)`. And suppose that I don't know that `c` is inside `a.b` - how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to parse the module's source code and extract imports:

```
import sys
import ast
import inspect


def find_imports(module):
    code = inspect.getsource(module)
    tree = ast.parse(code)

    imports = set()
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
            imports.update(alias.name for alias in node.names)
        elif isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):
            imports.add(node.module)
            for alias in node.names:
                module_name = '{}.{}'.format(node.module, alias.name)
                if module_name in sys.modules:
                    imports.add(module_name)

    return imports
```

Keep in mind that this only works if the module's source is available as plain python code.

---

As an example, consider this module:

```
from os.path import isfile
from importlib import util
import urllib.request as urlquest
import urllib.parse
import sys
```

The output for this module would be

```
{'sys', 'urllib.request', 'os.path', 'importlib', 'importlib.util', 'urllib.parse'}
```

---

## Notes:

1. This code also catches imports in functions, not just imports in the global scope.
2. If the code performs an import like `from module import submodule`, `"module.submodule"` will appear in the output. However, if the code performs an import like `from module import non_module`, only `"module"` will appear in the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solves my problem. But note that it fails when imports are done from within functions (which is really not good practice, but it is done a few times throughout my project's code...)

Comment: @ezer1337 Code updated; imports in functions should work now.